# watir 6.1.0 / selenium-webdriver 3.0.5 does not currently support setting the Window Position

Tags: selenium-webdriver, watir

```
browser.window.move_to(0, 0) if ENV['HEADLESS']==false
```

Getting the following error message with calling:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnsupportedOperationError: The W3C standard does not currently support setting the Window Position
```

While this does not block us from moving forward (just commented the code for now), it is something that we do need since we work with multiple monitors.

Comment: `watir-webdriver 3.x`?  Do you mean `selenium-webdriver 3.X.X`?  You should edit your question and include the exact gem versions for the gems that you're using.